# Error: Expected spy MovieService.getWatchListedMovies to have been called. angular Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spy

- A component file called **watchlist** which dependent on
  **MovieService(service)** to fetch movie.
- calling ngOnInit() will invoke MovieService.getWatchlistedMovies()
- the component code is given below,

```js
export class WatchlistComponent implements OnInit {

  movies: Array<Movie>;
  movieType:string;
  
  constructor(private movieService:MovieService,private route:ActivatedRoute) { 

    this.movies=[];
    this.route.data.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.movieType=data.movieType
    });
   
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.movieService.getWatchListedMovies()
    .subscribe((movies)=>{
     this.movies.push(...movies);
       },
       this.handleErrors()
       );

  }
```

- Unit testing on the **component(watchlist)** using *jasmine.spy* object on **movieService(Service)**
- watchlist.spec.ts file code as follow,

```js
describe('WatchlistComponent', () => {
  let component: WatchlistComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WatchlistComponent>;
  let movieServiceFake:jasmine.SpyObj<MovieService>;
  let movieService;
  let stubTmdbMovies: Movie[];
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    movieServiceFake = jasmine.createSpyObj('MovieService', ['getWatchListedMovies']);


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MovieModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [{ provide: MovieService, useValue: movieServiceFake }]
    })
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WatchlistComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    movieServiceFake = TestBed.get(MovieService);
  });

  it('should create watchlist', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call ngOnInIt', () => {
    //Arrange
    let spyOnComponent = spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit');
    movieServiceFake.getWatchListedMovies.and.callFake(() => { return of(stubTmdbMovies) });
    //Act
    component.ngOnInit();
    //Assert
    expect(spyOnComponent).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(movieServiceFake.getWatchListedMovies).toHaveBeenCalled();//error line
  });
});
```

`**MovieModule** where I have registered **watchlist** and **MovieService.** as below

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MovieRouterModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule
      ],
  declarations: [ContainerComponent,TmdbContainerComponent,TumbnailComponent, WatchlistComponent, MovieDetailsComponent],
  
  exports:[
    MovieRouterModule,
    TumbnailComponent,
    ContainerComponent,
    TmdbContainerComponent
  ],
  providers:[
    MovieService
  ]
})
export class MovieModule { }
```

Comment: Hi everyone, please look into it.

Comment: Hello Arun, can you add some points character on some sentences so that your question is more readable. Avoid to use long sentence. Explain also the context, the language and give more information. Giving some keys as Angular or Unit-Testing is good but not enough. I have read you question 3 times and I think that it can be improved.

Comment: Try to substitute `getWatchListedMovies.and.callFake(() => { return of(stubTmdbMovies) });` with `getWatchListedMovies.and.callFake(() => console.log("I have been called"));` and check whether it prints the message into the console

Comment: @schlebe thanks for your feedback. I will update my question.

Comment: @AmirArbabian I tried it and there is empty console log only. Is there any other solution?

Comment: It means that your fake service object in test is not the same object that you get in component.

Comment: Try removing `let spyOnComponent = spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit');`, `expect(spyOnComponent).toHaveBeenCalled();` and `movieServiceFake = TestBed.get(MovieService);`

Comment: Sorry but I have still some difficulties to read what you write. Some of your sentence don't have any verb. Can you check again. To add some paragraph add empty line and use `text` to highlight your text in normal sentence. It is just advise to improve your current question and any new questions wyou will post in the future. Can you also repeat your question sentence at end of your post in adding '?' character ? I will now make some change in your question so that you can see how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, try to move line

```
movieServiceFake = TestBed.get(MovieService);
```

into the beginning of the test, like

```
it('should call ngOnInIt', () => {
    movieServiceFake = TestBed.get(MovieService);
    ....
});
```

Comment: @Amit The moving " tesdbed.get " inside " it "also not solving the issue.

Comment: Ok, can you add then code how you register `WatchlistComponent` and `MovieService` in module? That would help.

Comment: @Amit I have post the module.ts file. Please have a look and help me.

Comment: Ok, so can you check whether it's the only registration of `MovieService`, because you can have a `MovieService` registered also on component level in `@Component` decorator and therefore you get the real service in your component instead mocked one